# Cell values based on applied filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to make cell value equal to currently applied filter?

I have column with data like: 001.1, 002.1, 003.1... (I have 100 rows) I need L1 cell (for example) to be equal to selected filter of that column.

So if I filter 002.1, then L1 = 002.1

How can I reach this please easier than like this?

```
Sub filtr()
If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_Lokace").SlicerItems("001.1").Selected = True Then
    Range("L1") = "001.1"
    Else
        If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Průřez_Lokace").SlicerItems("002.1").Selected = True Then
            Range("L1") = "002.1"
        End If
End If
End Sub
```

Or maybe something like this?

```
For i = 1 To 120
    If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Prùøez_Lokace").SlicerItems(""00" & i & ".1"").Selected = True Then
        Range("L1") = "00" & i & ".1"
    End If
Next i
```

Or something like this?

```
For i = 1 To 9
    x = "00" & i & ".1"
    If ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches("Prùøez_Lokace").SlicerItems(x).Selected = True Then
        Range("L1") = x
    End If
Next i
```

Unfortunately first (the most complicated) is working of course, but other two not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a super simple example:

- one column
- one criterium
- autofilter

[image]

If the user sets the *AutoFilter* to display *Robert* and runs this macro:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, i As Integer
    Set rng = Range("A:A").Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    i = 0
    For Each r In rng
        If i = 1 Then
            Range("B1").Value = r.Value
            Exit Sub
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Next r
End Sub
```

Then Robert will be placed in cell **B1**.  This takes advantage of the fact that what is displayed in column **A** *(other than the header)* matches the criterium.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start:https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/591287-start-macro-when-changing-value-slicer.html

Use this sub in your workbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetPivotTableChangeSync(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As PivotTable)
    'your macro
End Sub
```

I only played with it a little (sticking in a msgbox to pop up every time a slicer button is clicked), but it should be more elegant in that you don't need to run the VBA every time after you click on a slicer button.